# Error in my Code's For Loop?

Tags: java, servlets, for-loop

I am trying to break a sentence without spaces into sets of 3 words. Below is the sentence.

```
MyNamePanBokVa
```

Following is my code

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        //String[] listOfWords = request.getParameter("wordList").trim().split("\n");
        //int percentage = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("percentage"));

        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

        int numberOfKnownWords = 0;

        //Read the Hash File
        String str = "";
        File inputFile = new File("C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/Test.txt");
        HashSet<String>set = new HashSet<String>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));

        while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
            int lastIndex = 0;

            for(int i=0;i<=str.length();i=i+3)
            {
                try
                {
                    String stringPiece = str.substring(i, i+3);
                    lastIndex = i;
                    pw.println(stringPiece);
                }
                catch(Exception arr)
                {
                    String stringPiece = str.substring(lastIndex, str.length());
                    pw.println(stringPiece);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Unfortunatly this generates the following output.

```
MyN
ame
Pan
Bok
BokVa
```

This should be,

```
MyN
ame
Pan
Bok
Bok
Va
```

I guess there is an error in my for loop, but I can't spot it. What's wrong here?

Comment: How can you expect a return of twice `Bok`?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code step by step? It should become clear where the problem is.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `My` and  `Name` instead of `MyN` and `ame` in your expected output?

Comment: @AxelAmthor _"..to break a sentence without spaces into sets of **3 words** ."_

Comment: These are neither 3 words (the result has 5 words) nor is there any sophisticated other rule than splitting the stuff in to strings of 3 Chars each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put lastIndex assignment before getting stringPiece. In above code when you try to get stringPiece at that time exception will get generated and lastindex will become 9 so last prnted string is wrong.

Make your for loop as below.

```
for(int i=0;i<=str.length();i=i+3)
{
   try
   {
        lastIndex = i;
        String stringPiece = str.substring(i, i+3);
        pw.println(stringPiece);
   }
   catch(Exception arr){
       String stringPiece = str.substring(lastIndex, str.length());
       pw.println(stringPiece);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Think of the case when `i` is at V.

```
MyNamePanBokVa
            ^
```

i = 12
Output so far :

```
MyN
ame
Pan
Bok


   {
     String stringPiece = str.substring(i, i+3); 
    //throws exception, lastindex is not updated
     lastIndex = i;
    }
    catch(Exception arr)
                    {       
                        String stringPiece = str.substring(lastIndex, str.length());
                        // lastIndex =9 prints BokVa
                        pw.println(stringPiece);
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignment should be

```
 lastIndex = i+3;
```

Because the `lastIndex` will not be set if `str.substring(i, i+3);` throws `Exception`

Answer (score 1):

Could be done much simpler:

```
    while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
    {
        String [] pieces = str.split("(...)/g");
        for(int i=0;i<=pieces.length();i++)
        {
           pw.println(pieces[i]);
        }
     }
```

Comment: This is going to help me one day. +1 from me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not in your loop. It's how you detect that you have to print the last part.

```
try {
    String stringPiece = str.substring(i, i+3);
    lastIndex = i;
```

`str.substring` throws an exception because `i+3` is out of bounds in the last iteration. The `try` block will be left immediately and execution continues in `catch`. But you did not modify `lastIndex` yet and the `catch` block will print the value one iteration before the current.

To fix your problem, swap the order in the try block

```
try {
    lastIndex = i;
    String stringPiece = str.substring(i, i+3);
```

Answer (score 0):

when i = 12 ， "str.substring(i, i+3)" will throw exception. because length is 14. 12 + 3 is 15. lastIndex now is last time's 9. in catch ,"String stringPiece = str.substring(lastIndex, str.length());" equals to "String stringPiece = str.substring(9, 14);" now ,u get BokVa in the end.